# PHP check postal code in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a script to check someone's details they enter in a HTML form.

I have the code fine but i have realised if they type the postcode in a different format to whats in the database its going to error.

do i just take the POSTed postcode and change the format, if so whats the best way of making whats typed one format?

for example, in the database there is a row with the postal code `SS9 5LY` but if someone types it as `SS95LY` or `ss9 5ly` it wont match

Comment: Give us a number, example or something ...

Comment: Can you post here some samples of common postal codes formats in your country? Are they num-only or can they contain a letter?

Comment: Use methods like [string_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to replace commonly used characters (spaces and the like) with empty values to 'normalize' your input both before saving and comparing.

Comment: How many different ways are there they could enter it? You could always have an error message fade in that says, "Postal Code must be in this format: XXX XXX, or XXXXXX" with the Xs being an example

Comment: strip and tighten both down to lower case without space n stuff to `ss95ly` then compare

Answer (score 1):

First, take a look to [ZIP (POSTAL) Code Validation Regex](http://www.pixelenvision.com/1708/zip-postal-code-validation-regex-php-code-for-12-countries/). Also, try to use a database records in your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Have thousants of approachs to solve your problem.

You can use [masked input](http://plugins.jquery.com/maskedinput/), you can validate the input text before send to database using 
[RegularExpression](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php). And many others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)** to remove any unwanted characters from the input, convert everything to **[upper case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php)** and finally add the space after the third character using **[`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)**:

```
$postcode = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", "", $postcode);
$postcode = strtoupper($postcode);
$postcode = substr($postcode, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($postcode, 3);
```